# Error in sql request Undeclared variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Good evening! Can you help me with this problems? This request

```
 "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE save=1"
```

return this error

> "Undeclared variable: 0",

why? what`s wrong? Here is a database [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbwhy.png) 
This is code:
    [php]

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$matherial_base."` WHERE save=1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Error with request ($sql): " . mysql_error();
    exit;}
//Counting
@$col = mysql_num_rows($result);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
    echo 'Here is nothing, add some!';
}
```

Comment: the code in your question is not related to your error .. so  .. add the rest of the code

Comment: Show us the code where you actually trying to show the result. The problem is there.

Comment: [php] $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$matherial_base."` WHERE save=1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo Error with request ($sql): " . mysql_error();
    exit;}
//Counting
@$col = mysql_num_rows($result);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
    echo 'Here is nothing, add some!';
}